# Curtains.js Smooth Scroll Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, locomotivejs, curtains.js

**I trying ton implement smooth scroll of [locomotive-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/locomotive-scroll) to [curtains](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-curtains) in Reactjs. But he still doesn't work...**

I get errors :

> react_curtains__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Curtains.disableDrawing is not a function

or

> react_curtains__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Curtains.updateScrollValues is not a function

App.js

```
import React, {useRef, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import Home from './Pages/Home';
import {Curtains} from 'react-curtains'
import locomotiveScroll from 'locomotive-scroll';

function App() {

  const [useNativeScroll, setUseNativeScroll] = useState(null)

  const updateScroll = (xOffset, yOffset) => {
    // update our scroll manager values
    Curtains.updateScrollValues(xOffset, yOffset);
  }

  let container = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    
    const smoothScroll = new locomotiveScroll({
        el: container,
        smooth: true,
        inertia: 0.5,
        passive: true,
    });

    setUseNativeScroll(smoothScroll.isMobile)
    console.log(Curtains);

    if(!useNativeScroll) {
      // we'll render only while lerping the scroll
      console.log(Curtains.disableDrawing);
      Curtains.disableDrawing();
      smoothScroll.on('scroll', (obj) => {
          updateScroll(obj.scroll.x, obj.scroll.y);
  
          // render scene
          Curtains.needRender();
      });
    }

  }, []);

  return (
    <Curtains  watchScroll={useNativeScroll}  pixelRatio={Math.min(1.5, window.devicePixelRatio)}>
      <div ref={el => container = el} className="App">
        <Home />
      </div>
    </Curtains>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I use this repo : https://github.com/martinlaxenaire/curtainsjs/blob/master/examples/multiple-planes-scroll-effect-custom-scroll/js/multiple.planes.parallax.setup.js

I have to fix this if I want the canvas to move with the rest of the page

Comment: From what I can tell from the docs, `Curtains` is a React component, not an object you can call functions from.

Comment: Indeed. You might want to use the `useCurtains` hook instead of `useEffect`, that way you'd have access to the `curtains` instance. See: https://github.com/martinlaxenaire/react-curtains#usecurtains